# Ordering Numpy Arrays (Jointly)

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I am in a highschool class studying the world's greatest speeches. I need to make a study guide for all of the speeches. I have all the needed info in a .txt file (separated by tabs) following the pattern below:
[image: Example of information spreadsheet]

Using the following script I am able to generate all the data into a Microsoft Word Document (in a specific format) exactly how I desire:

```
"""
Opens data from speakers.txt and writes to new file in specific format
New file: SpeechNotes.docx
"""

import numpy as np
from docx import Document

def OpenData():
    global lines
    a = open('speakers.txt','r')
    lines = a.readlines()
    a.close()
    return lines

def CreateArrays():
    global FirstName
    global MiddleName
    global LastName
    global PgNum
    global WkNum
    global BirthDeath
    global Nationality

    lines1 = lines
    lines1 = [x for x in lines1]
    flds = [x.split() for x in lines]
    FirstName = np.array([x[0] for x in flds])
    MiddleName = np.array([x[1] for x in flds])
    LastName = np.array([x[2] for x in flds])
    PgNum = np.array([x[3] for x in flds])
    WkNum = np.array([x[4] for x in flds])
    BirthDeath = np.array([x[5] for x in flds])
    Nationality = np.array([x[6] for x in flds])

    return FirstName
    return MiddleName
    return LastName
    return PgNum
    return WkNum
    return BirthDeath
    return Nationality

def WriteToFile():
    document = Document()
    for i in range(len(FirstName)):
        if MiddleName[i] != "NULL":
            base = document.add_paragraph()
            base.add_run("%s %s %s\n" % (FirstName[i],MiddleName[i],LastName[i])).bold = True
            base.add_run("Life span: %s\n" % (BirthDeath[i]))
            base.add_run("Nationality: %s\n" % (Nationality[i]))
            base.add_run("Page Number: %s\n" % (PgNum[i]))
            base.add_run("Week: %s\n" % (WkNum[i]))
            document.add_page_break()

        if MiddleName[i] == "NULL":
            base = document.add_paragraph()
            base.add_run("%s %s\n" % (FirstName[i],LastName[i])).bold = True
            base.add_run("Life span: %s\n" % (BirthDeath[i]))
            base.add_run("Nationality: %s\n" % (Nationality[i]))
            base.add_run("Page Number: %s\n" % (PgNum[i]))
            base.add_run("Week: %s\n" % (WkNum[i]))
            document.add_page_break()

    document.save("SpeechNotes.docx")

if __name__ == "__main__":            
    OpenData()
    CreateArrays()
    WriteToFile()
```

The problem is that there is no order to this format. I would like to organize the speakers by their death date. I know how to order the numpy array (`sorted(SomeArray)`) but I then lose the correlation to the person's other information. Meaning if I order the death dates, then they will no longer correlate to the proper name.

In short, I need the death dates to be correlated to the other information specific for that speaker so that I may appropriately input the information into a Word Document when the death dates are chronologically ordered.

I have done much research in an attempt to find a solution, but I am still stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your function `CreateArrays` _only_ returns the `FirstName`. All other `return` statements in that function are ignored.

Comment: Not trying to make more work for you but, eventually, you will want to become familiar with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)  - after the learning curve, you like what it has to offer.

Comment: Does ```CreateArrays``` actually work?  How can a function have seven separate return statements?

Comment: You could pre-process the data by [reading it into a list of lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) (iterate over the file and split each line on tabs) then sorting on the  ```BirthDeath``` column - you will probably have to write a key function for that.  Then you probably won't need all those numpy arrays.

Comment: @DYZ the CreateArrays function actually works perfectly. I have never had any trouble with multiple return statements

Comment: @cnmcferen Yes it works, but only because all "returned" variables are global. Only the first return is actually executed, and even that one is redundant.

Comment: why don't you post your data as text so that someone can actually try this out?